# What I'm doing wrong on this class constructor?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, constructor, c++-cli

Visual Studio gives me the next error: 'Error: expected an identifier' on my .cpp file, where I'm declaring the function defined by it header on the .h file.

UI_Main.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace ProcessMonitoring {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for UI_Main
    /// </summary>
    public ref class UI_Main : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public: UI_Main(void);

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~UI_Main()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(UI_Main::typeid));
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // UI_Main
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^  >(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
            this->IsMdiContainer = true;
            this->Name = L"UI_Main";
            this->Text = L"PMonitoring";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    };
}
```

UI_Main.cpp (with error on UI_Main constructor):

```
#include "UI_Main.h"

namespace ProcessMonitoring{

    ProcessMonitoring::UI_Main(void){
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

};
```

It must be a very simple fail, but I'm not able to find it... Thank you in advance!

The errors after trying to debug are:

```
* error C2062: type 'void' unexpected
* error C2143: syntax_error: missing ';' before '{'
* error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
* IntelliSense: expected a ';'
* IntelliSense: expected an identifier
```

Comment: Please post the whole error message instead of an explanation of the error message.

Comment: This still doesn't seem like the full compilation errors... You should have indications *where* the "`type 'void'` is `unexpected`"

Comment: Deleting 'void' does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
namespace ProcessMonitoring{

    ProcessMonitoring::UI_Main(void){
```

should be

```
namespace ProcessMonitoring
{
    UI_Main::UI_Main(void)
    {
```

You've already given the namespace name, so you don't have to qualify with it again.  But you do have to use a fully-qualified name for a constructor definition that's outside the class, which means writing the class name twice.

The syntax you have:

```
ProcessMonitoring::UI_Main(identifier);
```

is a variable declaration, where the type is `::ProcessMonitoring::UI_Main` and the variable name is `identifier`, and the parentheses are redundant.  But `void` is a keyword, not a legal variable name, so the compiler rejects it with the error you saw.

Comment: This was the real solution! Thank you!